# Cannot publish Google Game services

Tags: google-play-games

I am trying to publish my game services using Play developer's console.

I am getting the "Ready to publish" button, and all lights are green but when I click the button I get a "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later." red message on the top of the screen.

I have tried logging out, switching browsers and updating some details but nothing helps.

Here is a screen shot of the situation:
[image]

Anyone have an idea what I might try to do in order to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have managed to solve this, and here is what I have done if anyone encounters the same problem. I have read and tried many solutions that were suggested in other posts and contacted Google but nothing worked.

The solution was to remove the linked apps, and add both of them again. I have 2 linked apps, one with the production certificate and one with the debug certificate.

This solution does not make any sense to me, and I guess it is some internal error on Google's side.